# ASP.NET Access Denied error when trying to write into Network Folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've a requirement of writing into a network folder from ASP.NET. 
So I just used Streamwriter class and it works fine when trying from local system using Visual studio web server. But when trying to host it into IIS on the same machine writing into network folder not working at all.

It saying

> Access to {\MYSERVER\specialfolder} is denied

So I thought it as some access issue. What I tried was as follows

- Changed Default Applicaiton Pool (Which is the pool using for my
  domain) identity to local system (And tried the other 4 ones too) :
  Still the error
- Authentication change for my site. Change from
  Anonymous for specific user IUSR into Application pool Identity : **No
  help**
- Right clicked on my site and then selected edit permission, then
  specified write permission for IIS_IUSRS group : **Not worked**
- Also I tried, Right Click on the network folder itself -> security ->
  But there is not IIS_IUSRS group

  What else I'm missing for having the write permission into network
  folder.

**Details about my system**

- IIS 8.5
- WINDOWS SERVER 2012R2
- VISUAL STUDIO 2015

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the IIS use the LOCAL user which generated by the IIS, this is local computer account.

If you want to access another network folder, you should set the enough permission to the IIS application pool identity.

You should use AD to assain enough permission to a spcial AD account.

Alternatively, using ActiveDirectory you could create a Domain User account, configure the application pool identity to use that domain user, and grant that user access to the network files.

More details, you could refer to below article:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: I have the full access to that folder from the same system IIS is running without any trouble.

Comment: Could you please tell me which account you have set for your folder?